# EF Core and Automapper - filtering child records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I would like to make an EF Core call that returns a parent object with a filtered list of associated children and projects it to a dto. I would like to do this via an EF Core Linq query, I suspect the ProjectTo part is ignoring the filtering up to that point. Is it possible?

- EF Core 5.0
- Automapper 7.0.0

I have another query that gets a parent and includes all child records without a filter so if possible I would like to implement something outside of the Dto mapping configuration.

**Domain objects**

```
public class ParentThing
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ChildThing> ChildThings { get; set; }
}

public class ChildThing
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentThingId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ParentThing ParentThing { get; set; }
}
```

**Dtos**

```
public class ParentThingDto : IMapFrom<ParentThing>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ChildThingDto> ChildThings { get; set; }
}

public class ChildThingDto : IMapFrom<ChildThing>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

**Query**

```
var upUntilDate = new DateTime(2013,1,1);

return await _context.ParentThings
  .Where(x => x.Id == request.ParentThingId)
  .Include(x => x.ChildThings.Where(y => y.Date <= upUntilDate))
  .ProjectTo<ParentThingDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**What I get**

```
{
  "id": "a5c8f72a-4682-4f62-b231-4c77c0615b84",
  "name": "Parent thing 9",
  "childThings": [
    {
      "id": "ff5fda07-1c15-411c-b72e-e126b91513b3",
      "date": "2014-06-26T22:41:20.7141034"
    },
    {
      "id": "4dded8a3-2231-442e-b40a-1e114da2665a",
      "date": "2012-04-02T06:51:31.963399"
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I expect/want**

Note that I only get one child thing back instead of 2, this is because one child has a date after `2013-01-01` which is the filter point I would like.

```
{
  "id": "a5c8f72a-4682-4f62-b231-4c77c0615b84",
  "name": "Parent thing 9",
  "childThings": [
    {
      "id": "4dded8a3-2231-442e-b40a-1e114da2665a",
      "date": "2012-04-02T06:51:31.963399"
    }
  ]
}
```

Just a note to say `IMapFrom<T>` only does the following

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
{   
    void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
}
```

Comment: You can always write the filter in the AM configuration and then you don't need the `Include`, the way it usually works with `ProjectTo`.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu I've edited the question to be more clear; There are times where I would like to get the parent record without applying a filter and be able to share the Dto objects for each query. Hopefully that's possible but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK `Include` does not work when you project to custom dto projections, either manually through `Select` or by using AutoMapper.

Instead, use a custom profile

```
public class CustomProfile : Profile
    {
        public CustomProfile()
        {
            DateTime? upUntilDate = null;

            CreateMap<ParentThing, ParentThingDto>()
                .ForMember(m => m.ChildThings, opt => 
                    opt.MapFrom(m => m.ChildThings.Where(y => 
                       upUntilDate.HasValue ? y.Date <= upUntilDate : true))
                    );
        }
    }
```

and then when you project you add the `upUntilDate` argument in the `ProjectTo`

```
var upUntilDate = new DateTime(2013,1,1);

return await _context.ParentThings
  .Where(x => x.Id == request.ParentThingId)
  .ProjectTo<ParentThingDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, new { upUntilDate })
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If you do not want to filter the children, just set upUntilDate to null (or do not add the argument).

Comment: Thanks for this, had to make a slight change to get it working with my project structure (and had to remove the `.ToList()` part but this works when using Automatter / EF Core. Ideally I wanted to avoid filtering within the mapping but I suspect that's not possible, so thank you for your input!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, glad to hear you could make it work.

Comment: Wow, finally a great answer for the same question I had for hours. That custom field for filtering inside mapper is all I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This feature [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) was introduced in EF5

> .Include(x => x.ChildThings.Where(y => y.Date <= upUntilDate))

before EF5 you are able to do like this

```
return await _context.ParentThings
  .Where(x => x.Id == request.ParentThingId)
  .Include(x => x.ChildThings)
  .Select(x=> new ParentThings{
     Id=x.Id,
     Name=x.Name
     ChildThings=x.ChildThings.Where(y => y.Date <= upUntilDate).ToList()
  }
  .ProjectTo<ParentThingDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're suggesting in relation to the issue I am having?

Comment: As far as I understood your filter doesn't work.
That is because you can not use filter in `Include` before EF5

Comment: Ahh I see, I am running EF5, I've updated the question stating this