# How do I conditionally select records from included entity in c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to fetch records of an entity(lets call this the parent entity) while including a related entity (lets call this the child entity) using some conditions.
Parent has many Children and Parent is referenced in Child table as a Parent Id. In fetching the Parent, I want to fetch the related Child(ren) based on certain conditions and not all Child(ren) records.

I added the child entity as a List in the DTO of the parent and my function to fetch is as follows:

```
_outputList = Mapper.ProjectTo<ParentDto>(
    ParentService.GetAllParentsQuery()
            .Include(x => x.Child.Where(a=> a.Start == '123' ))
            .Where(x =>
            x.FieldId.HasValue
            && x.FieldId == '123'
            )).ToList();
```

It fetches all the elements in the Included Child table and pays no respect to the where condition used.
Is there something I am missing or am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Can you try eliminating the AutoMapper factor out of the problem? Please note that part of the issue might lie in the projection there. If you want to keep the Mapper as part of the question, please include an AutoMapper tag to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66419236/5045688 / In my humble opinion, AutoMapper is the worst library in the .NET ecosystem. It creates more problems than it solves. With its use, you have to write more code than without it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the where into the include statement:

```
.Include(x => x.Child.Start == '123' && x.FieldId == '123')
```

I'm also making the assumption that Child is a single object, in which case you shouldn't need to be doing an additional `Where`.

Comment: I'm not allowed to access members of the child in such a direct manner